# Exclude array data from HTTP API results if entry is already in DB

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm calling a JSON API in Laravel via HTTP I then return that data to my view. Withing the view there is the option to add an item from the API to a DB. I've got this working fine. The bit I'm unsure how to do or approach is excluding the DB entries from showing. when I call the API again.

Here's my controller

```
public function listTopicsFromAPI()
{

    $response = Http::get('https://example.com/topics.json/search');
    $topics = $response->json();

    return view('admin.approve-topics', compact('topics'));
    
}
```

At some point in this function, I'm guessing I need to check my DB and compare to the API then exclude the items before presenting them back to the user.

The data returned from the API is an array of arrays and I need to check against the Title.
I've removed all the junk from the API dump so there's less to read for you.

```
array:25 [▼
  0 => array:21 [▼
    "Id" => "Topic title",
    "Title" => "Topic title"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to achieve this with the `Arr:where`

```
        $response = Http::get('https://example.com/data/divisions.json/search');
        $topicsResponse = $response->json();

        $currentTopics = Topic::get()->pluck('title');

        $topics = Arr::where(
            $topicsResponse,
            fn($array) => !$currentTopics->contains($array['Title'])
        );

        return view('admin.approve-topics', compact('topics'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the response is array you might want to try [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), iterate through the array and filter what you want to keep or dispose. Maybe it will solve your problem, or maybe someone else has a better approach.